# Покупка сертификата для связи WCF

Tags: windows, wcf, x509certificate

В течение долгого времени я использую "Makecert.exe", чтобы создать свой собственный сертификат, используемый для связи WCF между двумя клиентами.
Но я получаю отчеты об ошибках от пользователей, которые имеют более высокие процедуры безопасности/проверки, ошибки похожие на это:

> UntrustedRoot: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root
>   certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider

Я хочу избавиться от этого и приобрести сертификат. Предпочтительно с очень длинным срока годности. Но у меня остались вопросы:

1. Какой тип сертификата мне нужен? (Какое имя у этого типа сертификата?)
2. Где я могу купить это? Я был бы признателен, по крайней мере за одну
   строку о том, как я могу проверить тип сертификата.

Используется Tcp и Pipe биндинги(в них и прописан сертификат) с поддержкой сессий на основе callback вызовов.
Приложение у меня десктопное(сервер-много клиентов), тоесть это не веб сайт, я передаю информацию между двумя приложениями.

Comment: Просто ваш сертификат не входит в некий список доверенных, попасть туда должно быть ОЧЕНЬ сложно.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов нет, скорее всего там хватит обычного сертификата для https - просто подписать его должна доверенная контора.

Comment: а какой именно binding используется? http/https?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если используется http binding, то с серверной стороны должно хватить обычного single-domain https сертификата - т.к. от сервера при этом требуется лишь сертификат с

Enhanced Key Usage: Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1)

Обычные провайдеры сертификатов добавляют еще и Client Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2).

Проверить, хватит или нет, можно сгенерировав такой сертификат самому:

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN= myserver " -b 01/01/2000 -e 01/01/2050 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ss my -sr localMachine -sky exchange -sp  "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12
```

Если с ним приложение заработает - то заработает и с сертификатом от https провайдера.

Comment: Я обновил вопрос, к сожалению пока не могу проверить Ваш вариант, но если Вам есть чем дополнить буду благодарен.

Comment: @AiSatan с некоторой вероятностью сработает и для tcp - это зависит в основном от eku, а не от протокола. самый простой способ - взять бесплатный сертификат от StartSSL и проверить (правда, у них сайт на обслуживании до понедельника :). если сработает - покупать нормальный